# SUM of amounts with Dollar sign

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find out the SUM of values in a column, which is like '$2' and the type is varchar. How can I convert this on the fly find the SUM ?

Comment: post table schema, sample data and whatever you have tried.

Comment: do summation at the programming level instead of mysql...

Comment: In future, normalize your data!

Comment: Any update on my answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably better off using MySQL's implicit conversion:

```
select sum(trim(replace(col, '$', '')) + 0.0)
```

The silent conversion will include cents.  In addition, non-numeric characters are after the number will not cause an error.  The `trim()` will remove leading spaces which could also affect conversion.

Comment: I think it will include cents anyway

Comment: I am getting the SUM here. thanks @Gordon. But how can I get it as decimal ?

Comment: @HappyCoder . . . You can cast the result to `numeric`.

Answer (score 4):

This will remove the first characters ans summarizes the remaining:

```
select sum(substring(field,2)) from table
```

Comment: But I am getting all zeros there even though there is value in DB

Comment: As the type is varchar, do i need to convert it first before calculating the SUM  ?

Comment: This will not work for sure... data type is varchar and SUM don't work with varchar... ***WHO UPVOTED THIS???***

Comment: The current (edited) answer looks good. @HappyCoder are you certain that cutting off the first character of every value in the column is enough?

Comment: yeah but, I am getting zeros still as SUM

Comment: I don't know why, but your query is giving me error in mysql and sql too... check my link to test ur query... www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: I checked the documentation. You don't have to cast/convert anything. It should work fine by default if it contains only numbers. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert 1+'1' example.

Answer (score 1):

This is working query

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(substring(fieldName,2) AS UNSIGNED)) FROM tableName;
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e75da/8)