# SQL PHP Retrieve total money for a specific Store

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there a query that retrieve the TotalMoney,TotalPaidMoney,TotalReturnMoney for each StoreName.

Like:

```
StoreName|   TotalPaid      |     ToatalReturn       |  TotalMoney    
Pizza    | sum of PaidMoney |  sum of ReturnMoney    | sum of TotalMoney
         |
```

From this Table

```
Date | StoreName|PaidMoney| ReturnMoney| TotalMoney
*********
2014 | Pizaa    | 33$     | 12$        | 120$
2014   Main       12$       23$          123$
2014 | Pizaa    | 33$     | 12$        | 120$
2014 | Main     | 33$     | 12$        | 120$
```

Table I Have:
Store Table

Comment: Are the dollar characters actually part of the database field contents? If so, what would you like for $55+¢24?

Comment: Hello, Actually i Dont care about the $ character

Comment: Ok, so the fields are text fields containing the character and the $ needs to be ignored as not to break any calculations...?

Comment: This question has already an answer here - SUM and remove $ sign from field. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601482/sum-of-amounts-with-dollar-sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use a GROUP BY statement, like so :

```
SELECT StoreName, SUM(PaidMoney) as TotalPaid, SUM(ReturnMoney) as TotalReturn, SUM(TotalMoney) as TotalMoney FROM store_table GROUP BY StoreName
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked :D, 1 other thing can i sort this Monthly..like i have a complete date (2014-7-4) can i order them by month so the result woild be 2014-7-4 would have Pizaa with the total money etc....

Comment: Yes, you can : "SELECT DATE(`Date`), StoreName, SUM(PaidMoney) as TotalPaid, SUM(ReturnMoney) as TotalReturn, SUM(TotalMoney) as TotalMoney FROM store_table GROUP BY DATE(`Date`), StoreName"

Comment: Thank you Thomas.I Ment Sorting the data by store name and current month

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command:

```
SELECT SUM(PaidMoney) AS TotalPaid, SUM(ReturnMoney) AS TotalReturn, SUM(TotalMoney) AS TotalMoney FROM Table WHERE Store='Pizaa';
```

Or if you want all stores and regroup by store:

```
SELECT SUM(PaidMoney) AS TotalPaid, SUM(ReturnMoney) AS TotalReturn, SUM(TotalMoney) AS TotalMoney FROM Table GROUP BY Store;
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked :D, 1 other thing can i sort this Monthly..like i have a complete date (2014-7-4) can i order them by month so the result woild be 2014-7-4 would have Pizaa with the total money etc....

Answer (score 0):

If you really have this currency signs in your table, it might be a bit more complicated. I now assume, that you always have the $ sign as last sign in your column and that there are no decimal values:

```
SELECT 
StoreName,
SUM(PAID_MONEY_VALUE) AS SUM_PAID_MONEY_VALUE,
SUM(RETURN_MONEY_VALUE) AS SUM_RETURN_MONEY_VALUE,
SUM(TOTAL_MONEY_VALUE) AS SUM_TOTAL_MONEY_VALUE
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    StoreName,
    CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(PaidMoney, 1, LEN(PaidMoney - 1))) AS PAID_MONEY_VALUE,
    CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(ReturnMoney, 1, LEN(ReturnMoney - 1))) AS RETURN_MONEY_VALUE,
    CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(TotalMoney, 1, LEN(TotalMoney - 1))) AS TOTAL_MONEY_VALUE
    FROM <YOUR_TABLE>
) AS SUBQUERY
GROUP BY StoreName
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked :D, 1 other thing can i sort this Monthly..like i have a complete date (2014-7-4) can i order them by month so the result woild be 2014-7-4 would have Pizaa with the total money etc....

Comment: Yes, you could replace *SELECT StoreName* by *SELECT StoreName, DATEPART(m, <YOUR_DATETIME_COLUMN>)* and replace *GROUP BY StoreName* by *GROUP BY StoreName, DATEPART(m, <YOUR_DATETIME_COLUMN>)*
At the end you could add *ORDER BY *DATEPART(m, <YOUR_DATETIME_COLUMN>)*