# How to add the float values of one column from the database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch the total bill amount of particular day, but in my database all the amount are inserted with "£" symbol. Now I want to sum all the column values.can anyone help me to find out

For example:
I have created a table called order and the columns are `id`, `totamt`. In `totamt` column data is inserted like float values eg. `£2.00`, `£90.00` etc...

I have tried to add the values using Sum function in sql query. It adds the value but the total amount is wrong.

Comment: Paste some of the data from your table.

Comment: The only logical solution to me is to split the column in two columns, one with the amount and one with the currency.

Comment: how to sum the float values?

Comment: They're not float values, they're strings.

Comment: You need to replace it as => select sum(trim(replace(col, '£', '')) + 0.0)

Link => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601482/sum-of-amounts-with-dollar-sign

Answer (score 0):

I guess, as others in comments have guessed, your `totamt` column has a `VARCHAR()` data type, not the `FLOAT` data type you mentioned in your question.

To solve this problem the best way, you should rework your database so your `totamt` column has a `DECIMAL(12,2)` data type. Why? Strings are hard to use for arithmetic operations as you have discovered.  Also, floating-point arithmetic has some quirks making it not so good for money values.

In the meantime, you need to add code to your query to edit your `totamt` strings so they look like numbers before you give them to the `SUM()` operation.

This may work for you to convert your values. It removes the currency symbols and expresses the amount as a decimal value.

```
     CONVERT(REPLACE(totamt,'£', ''), DECIMAL(12,2)) totamt
```

So you can then do

```
     SELECT SUM(CONVERT(REPLACE(totamt,'£', ''), DECIMAL(12,2))) grand_total,
            id
       FROM table
      GROUP BY id
```